# Regular sized text vs regularly sized text

Tags: adjectives, phrase-choice, hyphens

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- *A regular sized text*
- *A regular-sized text*
- *A regularly sized text*

Example of context:

> Short text classification is much harder than text classification, as a short text contains fewer clues than a *regular sized text*.

I know I could use some post-nominal forms such as *a text of regular size*, but I am curious to know whether there exist some prenominal solutions.

Comment: To me, *regularly sized* sounds like it is *sized on a regular basis* rather than being *of a regular size*.

Comment: If you're going to use "short" you might as well use "long". A short text contains fewer clues than the typical "long" text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AmE:

a text of normal size = a normal size text = a normal sized text

You could swap **regular** in there for **normal** and get along fine in the US of A.

But when you use adverbs **regularly** or **normally**, then "size/sized" does not mean "to be of a certain size" but rather  "to measure the size of"  or "to set the size of".

A regularly sized text is (incongruously) one whose size is regularly *taken* or measured.

Answer (score 2):

Note that ***regular*** here is very much an *American* synonym for ***normal***. But the same usage constraints apply to both, so consider [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20normal-sized%2Ca%20normal%20sized%2Ca%20normally-sized%2Ca%20normally%20sized&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20normal%20-%20sized%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20normal%20sized%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20normally%20-%20sized%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20normally%20sized%3B%2Cc0) showing relative prevalence...

[image]

As you can see, we don't *normally* use the explicitly adverbial form in [prenominal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prenominal) contexts where the compound adjective contains a past tense verb form (*sized* in this case).